# Python regex : extract multiple pattern in series containing decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Say, I have a string

```
1. ACTNOWQUICK3 1234.56 1234.98 HYE912630964589376 PLUTO THEATRE OTHER WUN Cool Beans KIng
2. Cash WithdrawalATM 50.00 ABC 1111.22 23523455A
3. ACTNOWQUICK 76.53 653.24 HYE91234234589376 WiN OTHR JOHNKLING
```

I need to extract pattern from this such that, I get everything before the first numerical value, everything after it and also the two numerical values . Note that its guranteed that there will be only 2 numeric int/decimal values in the string with space before and after

this is what I have tried but its not giving me the expected output :

```
pattern = '(.*)([0-9]*[,.][0-9]*).*([0-9]*[,.][0-9]*)(.*)'
```

What was expected :

```
1. "ACTNOWQUICK3", 1234.56, 1234.98, "HYE912630964589376 PLUTO THEATRE OTHER WUN Cool Beans KIng"
2. "Cash WithdrawalATM", 50.00, 1111.22, "23523455A"
3. "ACTNOWQUICK", 76.53, 653.24, "HYE91234234589376 WiN OTHR JOHNKLING"
```

Comment: Replacing the first two `.*` by `.+?` should help.

Comment: what's the difference? because when I try this I don't get the 4th group correctly

Comment: `+` means one or more occurences, `*` means 0 or more.

Comment: @LukasNeugebauer I obviously know that. Sorry if I was not clear I meant how exactly it helps in my case? I need the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a greedy quantifier. As Michael recommends, just change the first two `.*` to lazy adding a `?` after it. And add a white space in the first and last parenthesis.

```
pattern = '(.*?) ([0-9]+[,.][0-9]+).*?([0-9]+[,.][0-9]+) (.*)'
```

This works because you want to repeat the first patterns as few as possible.

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/PVR6bd/1